# How to get ID or primary key value of register clicked on listview in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new to Android programming and I'm making an app on Android Studio, one of its functions would be the CRUD in sqlite with the app, registering, displaying and manipulating items. These items are eliminated in a listview which would be filled with data from an adapter. But then my serious question, how do I when I click on a listview item, get an ID or key field value from the database corresponding to the record I clicked on the listview? If someone can send me a snippet of code or an article about it would help a lot, because I still couldn't find anything to solve my question.

Comment: Well you were the one who bound your data to each row of the `ListView` in the first place. So you should still have access to that dataset, with the right ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved to solve the problem, using more one textview, but for display the id of records from database in listview, and i used this value when clicked in line from listview.

Follow the code:

```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    
                    ItemList item = adapter.getItem(position);//pega valores de uma linha a partir da posição do item na lista array.
                    itemPos = position; //positions of listView objects.
    
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Item selected: "+ item.getId(),   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    showPopup(adapterView);
            }
```

Where the variable "item" corresponds to the TextView value of the database ID, where the "getId" method is used, which is the function to define and obtain from another activity to send values ​​to the Adapter, and in this case, to obtain values ​​for listView Fragment.

I hope this solution will help other people with related problems.

And I have a lot to thank @dinkar_kumar for the help

Answer (score 1):

A basic snippet to get you started.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                textView.setText("The item you clicked is : " + selectedItem);
             }
          });
```

Comment: this not solve my problem, because this gets position of listview element and not gets the register id in database

Comment: What I want is a code that takes the Primary Key ID from the data that is not in the clicked element, for example, I clicked on the first line of the listView, and that line has the data corresponding to the Database ID number 5, what if I don’t know how to get this value, or I can end up getting the value 1, by taking the position value of the element, and not the value 5 that corresponds to the ID of the bank information clicked line

Comment: why would you be taking position as your Id, the ListView can be created with Any custom java class not only with String value. So If you created listView with each item as an Object of your class then that object will be having key field also.
For example:
Assume each entry is of Student info and your primary key is role number. then each item in List View will be of a Java Class Student having all the relevant info you need like name,roll_numer,address etc associated with.
So whenever you click the item in the listview you know the Object you clicked and you can get roll number from that

Comment: I understand, but should I insert the primary key values ​​into the listview object array?

Comment: You don't have to worry about position as the key because the item at that position which is visible to user and clicked by them already hold the key in the Object itself.

Comment: ok, so should i save the bank id values ​​in the listview array and be using them for sql operations? How would it work? because taking the id the way you use it is not working for me.

Comment: You have to show me some code to help you out

Comment: not in the comment but in your question it self.

Comment: I found a solution, before I will test it here, because I would be creating another textview object to be displaying the database record ID, and obtaining this value by clicking on it to use in queries, is that what you wanted to say?

Comment: Ya you can try that, let me know if that still didn't help you and you still need my help

Comment: I achivied, my friend, because I created another textview to display the Id of the database records and I was able to get this value when clicked on the listview line

Answer (score 0):

Setting up click listener on list view will do the trick.

**setOnItemClickListener** is the method to set the click listener